# Is it possible to change amount of Azure Redis databases?

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache

The following article tells that the "default" Redis server configuration in Azure has 16 Redis databases: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/cbe6d113-7bdc-4664-a59d-ff0df6f4e214#RedisConfig.

It also states that:

> Any values that are configurable, such as max-memory-policy, are
>   configurable through the portal.

As for me I've not found such setting in Azure Portal.

Is it possible to change amount of Azure Redis databases?

Comment: Side note: To my knowledge the latest release of Redis (3.0) does not support multiple databases. MS Azure uses the windows clone, which is not at 3.0 yet, but they will most probably follow. I'd steer away from it, it's not recommended (although valid in Redis 2.x).

Comment: @TwBert, I've just installed Redis 3.0 and databases are still supported. Redis Cluster supports the only database unlike standalone instance.

Comment: Can you please open a request here http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169382-cache

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov Apparently I made a wrong assumption (Redis Cluster -> Redis 3.0). Thanks for the feedback, good to know.

Comment: @pranavrastogi, done: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169382-cache/suggestions/7748541-add-ability-to-change-amount-of-redis-databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Pranav, this is not yet possible, but is something we are considering in the near future.

Update: Yes, we rolled this feature out, but it isn't a configuration setting, it is a limit based on the size of cache instance you have chosen.  For instance, a C1 still has a limit of 16, but a C4 has up to 32.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#default-redis-server-configuration for more details

Comment: is this possible yet please?